# Trying to Hyperlink a formula to another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a hyperlink based of the following formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('TRAY ROUTES AND PACKS'!$F$3:$F$399,MATCH($K5,'TRAY ROUTES AND PACKS'!$B$3:$B$339,0),0),"NO SHARED ROUTE")
```

I am trying to match a specific cable route `$K5`to another sheet called TRAY ROUTES AND PACKS in column B. Once that match is found in B, I want to then link to the name found in the Column F that also has an online hyperlink attached.
I have tried:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('TRAY ROUTES AND PACKS'!$F$3:$F$399,HYPERLINK(MATCH($K4,'TRAY ROUTES AND PACKS'!$B$3:$B$339,0),0)),"NO SHARED ROUTE")
```

But I receive a SPILL error, any suggestions?

Comment: put the thing you find inside the hyper link.  ie.  HYPERLINK(INDEX(RANGE,MATCH(),MATCH()))  as opposed to INDEX(RANGE,HYPERLINK(MATCH())) type deal.

Comment: I tried this: =IFERROR(HYPERLINK(INDEX('TRAY ROUTES AND PACKS'!$F$3:$F$399,MATCH($K4,'TRAY ROUTES AND PACKS'!$B$3:$B$339,0),0)),"NO SHARED ROUTE"), but now I receive this error, "unable to open [some webpage] (HTTP/1.0 404). I want to link this sheet to another sheet where they will find the next thing to click on....does that make sense?

Comment: break your formula down into parts an make sure each part is working.